# Not able to link to compiled /.so source libraries in C++

Tags: mysql, g++, cmake, undefined-reference, mysqlbinlog

I am new to C++. I am trying to use the MySQL replication in a C++ program to read the binlogs from MySQL.

I got the header files and `.cpp` source files from Internet. Now I've placed the header files in `/usr/include/mysql` folder and set the path of the `CPLUS_INCLUDE_PATH` to point to it. It is able to use the header files. Also, I've placed the `.cpp` files in `/usr/lib64/mysql` folder and I compiled all `.cpp` files to create the `.o` files in the same directory.

But when I compile my program using `g++` (`g++ -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysql/ -g  bin_log.cpp -o bin_log.out`), I am getting Undefined Reference to error for all the methods I am trying to invoke. See below:

```
/home/oracle/MySQL_To_Db2_Replication/bin_log.cpp:17:
undefined reference to `mysql::system::create_transport(char const*)
undefined reference to `mysql::Binary_log::Binary_log(mysql::system::Binary_log_driver*)'
undefined reference to `mysql::Binary_log::connect()'
undefined reference to `mysql::Binary_log::wait_for_next_event(mysql::Binary_log_event**)'
undefined reference to `mysql::Binary_log::get_position()'
```

I've also tried creating a .so file and linking it while compiling but it's not working. (I used `g++ -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysql/binlogapi.so -g  bin_log.cpp -o bin_log.out`).

I've tried building the libraries using `cmake`, but no luck. 
Could any guess what could be the problem with this? I think I am missing something basic.

Comment: `-L` takes the library search path, not the .so file, for the second example.

Comment: You need to link the library using the `-l` option. Like if the library is `libmysql.so` then try `g++ source.cpp -lmysql` . Else  `g++ source.c /path/to/the/object_code.so` should work.

Comment: @phoxis: I tried removing the .so and just using the path to mysql lib. But I am still getting the same error.

Comment: I think you need to specify the library to be linked using the `-l` switch.

Comment: -l is working. At least it is showing that it is using the .so library. But I am getting undefined reference error for other things which seem to be part of the header but not the definition. Does that mean that the .cpp is not comprehensive or completely defined.

Comment: Nothing to do with compilation. I do not know the library to link for your case. I can give example:
`gcc file.c -lm`  links the `libm` library. Similarly you should link a library which has to be linked in your case.

Comment: I am saying that it is able to link it now using the -l option. But I am getting undefined reference error for some other things.
/usr/lib64/mysql/libbinlogapi.so: undefined reference to `cli_safe_read'
/usr/lib64/mysql/libbinlogapi.so: undefined reference to `mysql_query'
/usr/lib64/mysql/libbinlogapi.so: undefined reference to `mysql_unix_port'
/usr/lib64/mysql/libbinlogapi.so: undefined reference to `mysql_init'

Comment: Is it the incorrect library ?

Comment: No, the library is correct. I mean I have created it manually by compiling the .cpp files I got on the internet as a bunch.  The undefined references are mainly for one of the .cpp files (tcp_driver.cpp). It refers to some of the methods which aren't defined in it.  Maybe some other header file.

Comment: You may wish to follow a guide on how to use the MySQL Replication Listener API  http://intuitive-search.blogspot.com/2011/07/binary-log-api- and-replication-listener.html

Answer (score 0):

You're doing it wrong.

Libraries to be linked to must come *after* the objects that require them, so put the command to link to `libbinlogapi.so` after your `.cpp` file, and as it depende on the MySQL client API you also need to link to that, which is usually called `libmysqlclient.so`, so you want something like this:

```
g++ -I/usr/include/mysql -L/usr/lib64/mysql/ -g bin_log.cpp -o bin_log.out -lbinlogapi.so -lmysqlclient
```